# Why is the KILL signal handler not executing when my child process dies

Tags: bash

I have migrated some scripts from ksh to bash and I have observed very strange behavior in bash. I was able to reduce to a very short snippet.

```
echo first test
LC_ALL=C xclock &
Active_pid=$!

sleep 1

kill -9 $Active_pid
sleep 1

echo second test
LC_ALL=C xclock &
Active_pid=$!

sleep 1
trap "echo Signal SIGKILL caught"  9
kill -9 $Active_pid
sleep 1
```

The output is

```
first test
./mig_bash.sh: line 15:  4471 Killed                  LC_ALL=C xclock
second test
```

My problem was the production of the trace in the first test. I have tried to see if a signal was received. By trial and error, I wrote the "second test" that solve my problem. I do not understand it. How this removes the trace of the first test without executing `echo Signal SIGKILL` ?

I am completely lost.

Comment: The message about a killed child process is also suppressed if the process is `disown`-ed: `LC_ALL=C xclock & disown`

Comment: thank you. It does not explain my mystery, but it is a cleaner solution for my problem.

Comment: SIGKILL **cannot** be caught. That's why people use it instead of SIGTERM (because they don't trust the program to complete its cleanup-and-shutdown in a timely manner), and also why they **shouldn't** use it (because doing so means that programs can't flush their buffers, remove their temporary files, release SHM buffers, and otherwise exit in a way that lets them preserve data/state as much as possible).

Comment: (and since a trap fires based on signals you receive, not signals your children receive, a trap set for SIGKILL will by definition never fire).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I couldn't find anything in the bash documentation that would explain the observed behavior, so I turned to the source code. Debugging lead to the function [`notify_of_job_status()`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/jobs.c?h=bash-4.3#n3626). The [line that prints the message about a killed subprocess](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/jobs.c?h=bash-4.3#n3712) can be reached only if all of the following conditions hold:

1. the subprocess is registered in the job table (i.e. has not been `disown`-ed)
2. the shell was NOT started in interactive mode
3. the signal that terminated the child process is NOT trapped in the parent shell (see the [`signal_is_trapped (termsig) == 0` check](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/jobs.c?h=bash-4.3#n3708))

Demonstration:

```
$ cat test.sh 
echo Starting a subprocess
LC_ALL=C sleep 100 &
Active_pid=$!
case "$1" in
    disown)      disown ;;
    trapsigkill) trap "echo Signal SIGKILL caught"  9 ;;
esac
sleep 1
kill -9 $Active_pid
sleep 1
echo End of script

$ # Demonstrate the undesired message
$ bash test.sh 
Starting a subprocess
test.sh: line 14: 15269 Killed                  LC_ALL=C sleep 100
End of script

$ # Suppress the undesired message by disowning the child process
$ bash test.sh disown
Starting a subprocess
End of script

$ # Suppress the undesired message by trapping SIGKILL in the parent shell
$ bash test.sh trapsigkill
Starting a subprocess
End of script

$ # Suppress the undesired message by using an interactive shell
$ bash -i test.sh 
Starting a subprocess
End of script
```

> How this removes the trace of the first test without executing `echo Signal SIGKILL` ?

The trap is not executed since the `KILL` signal is received by the sub-process rather than the shell process for which the trap has been set. The effect of the trap on the diagnostics is in the (somewhat arguable) logic in the `notify_of_job_status()` function.